# how to create tooltips with javascript for tabs

Tags: javascript, events, tabs, onclick, tooltip

Hi I would like to use javascript to control what tooltip displays when a tab is rolled over depending on which tab was clicked.

```
 <li id='1tab_1a' class='selected'>a id='1link_1a'  title="Customer Info Screen"><span >Customer Info</span></a></li>
  <li id='1tab_1b' >a id='1link_1b'  title="Order Detail"  ><span>Order</span></a></li>

 <li id='1tab_1c' >a id='1link_1c'  title="Phone Detail" ><span>Phone:  7093521232</span></a></li>
```

For example when the Customer Info tab is selected I would like the tooltips to be like above but when Order is the tab selected I would like the 
tooltip to say Customer Info Detail, Order Detail Screen, and Phone Detail. How could I use an onclick event to control what tooltip is being 
displayed depending on which tab is selected? I have about 20 sets of customer info and sometimes not everyone contains all of the tabs and I 
would also like to be able to add more customers.

Comment: For clarity, what you're trying to accomplish is that when you click on the first <li> element (with id="1tab_1a"), the other two <li>s show up as a "tooltip" right?

Answer (score 0):

I've partially tested this code, and I think it may work for you. This assumes that the `<li>` are inside a `<ul>`, and you have added `onclick="onClick(this)"` to the `<a>` tags.

```
function onClick(obj) {
    var a, li, selected, ul = obj.parentNode.parentNode;

    for (var i=0; i<ul.childNodes.length; i++) {
    li = ul.childNodes[i];

        if (li.nodeName.toUpperCase()=="LI") {
            selected = (li.className=="selected");
            a = li.firstChild;

            switch (li.id) {
                case "1tab_1a": a.title = (selected)?"Customer Info Screen":"Customer Info Detail"; break;
                case "1tab_1b": a.title = (selected)?"Order Screen":"Order Detail"; break;
                case "1tab_1c": a.title = (selected)?"Phone Screen":"Phone Detail"; break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: It looks like your sample HTML code is missing some open tag symbols before the `<a>` tags.

EDIT: This method is based on the class attribute of the `<li>` tags. I'm not sure how you are currently changing that value to "selected". You could wrap it into this onclick function by adding the following to the first line under the `if`:

```
li.className = (li==obj.parentNode)?"selected":"";
```